# Why AlCl3 more acidic than FeBr3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

In compounds with lone pairs or with charge it is easy to predict acidity of compounds but how to describe acidic nature of  such ($\ce{FeBr3}$, $\ce{AlCl3}$) transition element compounds ?

Comment: Well, Al is smaller than Fe, and the formal charge is the same.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80375/alcl3-h2o-reaction

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89378/which-is-more-acidic-bf3-or-alcl3